# Bug in iPhone Library Access?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mpmediaitemcollection

This code:

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
NSArray *songsByArtist = [query collections];

for( MPMediaItemCollection *c in songsByArtist ) {
    NSLog(@"artist %@ has %u songs",[[c representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist], [[c items]count]);
}
```

works as expected. But this code:

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
NSArray *songsByArtist = [query collections];

for( MPMediaItemCollection *c in songsByArtist ) {
    NSLog(@"artist %@ has %u songs",[[c representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist], [c count]);
}
```

always prints "1" for the number of songs. Can anyone else confirm this issue? It seems like a bug when looking at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItemCollection_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMediaItemCollection/count).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're counting the collections in that query rather than the songs inside of it.

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
NSArray *songsByArtist = [query collections];

for( MPMediaItemCollection *c in songsByArtist ) {
        NSLog(@"artist %@ has %u songs",[[c representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist], [[c items] count]);
}
```